# Recursively search word in a matrix of characters

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a program for a homework using recursion to search for a word in a matrix (2x2 or more), it can be going from left to right or from up to down (no other directions), for example if I am searching for `ab` , in the matrix `[['a','b'],['c','d']]`, the program should return in what direction the word is written (across), the starting index(0), ending index(2), and the index of the row or column(0). 
My problem is that I have the idea of the recursion but, I can't implement it. I tried to break the problem down into more little proplems, like searching for the word in a given row, I started by thinking of the smallest case which is 2x2 matrix, at the first row and column, I need to search one to the right and one to the bottom of the first char, and check if they are equal to my given string, then give my recursion function a smaller problem with the index+1. 
However I can't think of what to make my function return at the base case of the recursion, been trying to solve it and think of ways to do it for two days, and I can't code what I think about or draw.

Note that I can't use any loops, I would really appreciate it if somone could push me in the right direction, any help would be pretty much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: more examples: 
 for input of matrix : `[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]` the outputs are:
with the string `ab` : across,0,0,2
with the string `be` : down,1,0,2 
with the string `ghi`: across,2,0,3

Comment: **the starting index(0), ending index(2), and the index of the row or column(0)** How is the starting index `0` and how is the ending index `2`? The index of `a` is `[0][0]` and of b `[0][1]`, shouldn't the ending index be `[0][1]`? Could you give some more examples for this? **and the index of the row or column(0)** of what row and collumn?

Comment: @Countour-Integral I added some more examples, sorry for not being clear enough

Comment: **Still**, how  is `1, 0, 2` the output of `be`. The **starting** index of what? The ending index of what? Which row or column are you talking about? The index of `b` is `[0][1]` and the index of `e` is `[1][1]`. So it is starting at index `[0][1]` and ending at `[1][1]`. How did you get `1` and `0`? Also what is the `2`?

Comment: @Countour-Integral it's how the question is stated, the 1,0,2 is the output of 'be' because 'be' is found in the second column (index 1) at the starting index 0 (first row), and it ends at index (1) second row, so they put the ending at 2.  the same for 'ghi', it's found at third row (index 2), starts at column(0) and ends at (2) so they put 3. you could say the end is plus one more than the last index. I'm sorry for the bad explanation

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the word we are looking for could be found starting from any place but we can move up to down or left to right only.

In that case, you should have a function that takes the start index and a direction and then the function keeps moving in the given direction starting from the given index and keeps moving until it doesn't find a mismatch, and it just returns true or false based on the match of the given string.

Now you need to call this function for each and every index of the matrix along with two directions up to down and left to right, and at any index, if you get the output of the function as true then you have found your answer.

This is a very basic idea to work, next it depends on you how you want to optimize the things in this method only.

---

Update:

To avoid using the loops.

The other way I can think of is that the function which we have defined now takes the row, column, and the string to find. So at each call, you will first check if the character at the given row and column matches the first character of the given string if so then it calls the two more functions, one in the right direction and the other in the down direction, along with the string with the first character removed.

Now to check all the columns of the matrix, you will anyway call the function in down and right direction with the exact same string.

The base case will be that if you reach the end of the string then you have found the answer and you will return True, otherwise False.

One more thing to notice here is that if any of the 4 function calls gives you a True response then the current row/column will also return True.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it, to be honest I tried to do this, but I lost track of the index's of the word, another question about calling the function for each and every index, I'm unallowed to use loops, do you have any hints on how to recursively go over all of the matrix? (in one row I can just send the first index and slice the first element and call function, but I'm lost with 2d matrix).

Comment: @Pwaol Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks alot I appreciate the explanation, I have succeeded finally after many hours of trying and with the help of people here, first I made two recursive functions, one searches rows and one searches columns, then made a recursive function that goes on index's from 0 to the list length, and calls my two functions.

Comment: That's great. Good luck!